# Python: Array indexing all the values in first index with Librosa

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, librosa

I'm trying to get the first value of my array, however, when I try to print the **bandwidth** first array value, it shows all the values of the array in the first index instead of just the first value itself.

If I try to print the second index of the array it gives me the error:

```
index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

So by printing the first value with the code below:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np

y, sr = librosa.load(filename)
onset_env = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y, sr=sr)
tempo = librosa.beat.tempo(onset_env, sr=sr)
sampleRate = librosa.get_samplerate(filename)
durationValue = librosa.get_duration(y, sr=sr)
duration = round(durationValue, 2)
bandwidth = librosa.feature.spectral_bandwidth(y=y, sr=sr)

print("Tempo: " + str(int(tempo)))
print("Sample Rate: " + str(int(sampleRate)))
print("Duration: " + str(duration))
print("Bandwidth: " + str(bandwidth[0]))
```

It gives me the following print log with all the values (instead of just the first value itself):

```
Tempo: 135
Sample Rate: 44100
Duration: 58.99
Bandwidth: [1696.55727753 1607.42642476 1626.93942805 ...  585.00089368 1148.95518802
3082.65000084]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem I was having was with a Numpy array so I would to specify the index value on the second value so I changed:

```
print("Bandwidth: " + str(bandwidth[0]))
```

to

```
print("Bandwidth: " + str(bandwidth[0][0]))
```

to which the print log returns a singular value:

```
Tempo: 135
Sample Rate: 44100
Duration: 58.99
Bandwidth: 1626.93942804681
```

I'm still learning about Numpy arrays but from my understanding (which most likely is wrong) is that I needed to select which array first and then which index value from that selected array.